How to calculate the received power in the case of multiple transmit antennas?
I want to calculate the received power of an antenna in the case of multiple transmit antennas. For simplicity, assume there are only two transmit antennas and the antenna configuration is shown in the picture below. This is more or less the same question as in Received power from multiple transmitters, however, in this case, the distances between the transmit antennas and the receiver (r1 and r2) are not equal.
Assume I know all the electrical parameters of the antennas (maximum gain, radiation patterns, transmit powers, initial phases, etc.) and they are identical for TX1 and TX2. The far-field conditions are met and the electric fields of both TX antennas are polarized perpendicular to the drawing plane. How can I calculate the received power in this scenario?
In the case of a single TX and RX antenna, we first calculate the time-averaged Poynting vector at the RX antenna's aperture and multiply it by the effective aperture area of the RX antenna. This is essentially how the Friis Transmission equation is derived.
However, I couldn't figure the case with 2 TX and 1 RX antennas. I calculated and summed up the electric field phasors at the RX antenna's aperture, but now I don't know how to proceed further. I can't simply calculate the resulting time-averaged Poynting vector and multiply it by the effective aperture area, because each TX path sees a different effective aperture area due to different incident directions.

